# Load related entities using .Find() method in an EF Core generic repository

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, repository-pattern

I created a generic repository worked with `Entity framework core` targeted `.Net 5`
I created a method that will receive a primary key value of an object and it (method) should select the object and load received related entities.

**I try :**

```
public virtual TEntity GetById( object pkValue , params Expression<Func<TEntity , object>>[] relatedEntitiesToBeLoaded )
{
    // Get one object using primary key
    var resultObject = Context.Set<TEntity>().Find( pkValue );

    // Load all selected objects from selected entities
    foreach ( var entityToLoad in relatedEntitiesToBeLoaded )
    {
        Context.Entry( resultObject ).Reference( entityToLoad.GetPropertyAccess().Name ).Load();
    }

    return resultObject;
}
```

But I got this error:

> InvalidOperationException: The navigation 'XEntity.XProperty' cannot
> be loaded because the entity is not being tracked. Navigations can
> only be loaded for tracked entities.

Please how can I fix this issue ?

Comment: Does [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/change-tracking/) solve your problem?

Comment: Any chance that your db context is set-up to "no tracking" mode by default? What does `Context.Entry( resultObject ).State` return?

Comment: @IvanStoev `Context.Entry( resultObject ).State` returns `Detached`

Comment: @JOCKH That's the problem, and normally `Find` returns tracked object. So again, check your code for `ChangeTracker.QueryTrackingBehavior = QueryTrackingBehavior.NoTracking;`. Or check `Context.ChangeTracker.QueryTrackingBehavior` value in the debugger.

Comment: What should I give to `Context.ChangeTracker.QueryTrackingBehavior` 
And really thank you for your time and effort

Comment: The better is to leave it as is by default which I guess is `TrackAll`. Or try calling `Context.Attach(resultObject);` right after `Find`. It depends, but that's what the error message is telling you - that `resultObject` must be tracked, i.e. the `State` at least must be `Unchanged` (or `Modified`, or `Added`, bit not `Detached` or `Deleted`).

Comment: @IvanStoev really really I appreciate this for you brother 
I wish god save you
you have the full right the problem with `Tracking ` `behavior`
thank you a lot again

Answer (score 0):

Stop creating generic repositories, it will probably fix the issue. Entity framework dbsets are repositories by itself.

Comment: You should start working on massive projects to understand why using repositories